# set exit status if perl -cw emits warning

Tags: perl

I'd like perl -cw ... to return a non-zero exit status if a compilation warning is emitted.

E.g. suppose `a.pm` is the file:

```
use warnings;
asd;
```

Then `perl -cw a.pm` reports:

```
Unquoted string "asd" may clash ...
Useless use of a constant in void context ...
a.pm syntax OK
```

and the exit status is set to 0. I'd like to be able to detect that compilation warnings were emitted - preferably though setting of the exit status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a warning handler in a `BEGIN` block (near the top of the script, so this block is parsed before the code that might trigger compile-time warnings), and tweak the exit status in an <strike>`END`</strike>`CHECK` block.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $warnings;
BEGIN {
    $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { $warnings++; CORE::warn @_ }
}
$used::only::once = 42;
CHECK {
    if ($^C && $warnings > 0) {
        exit $warnings;
    }
}
```

The [`$^C`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24COMPILING) variable is true if and only if you have invoked `perl` with the `-c` option.

Comment: In syntax checking mode END block not being invoked. You can check this very easy: `perl -c -e'END { print "End block\n" }'`. If it would - we could use just a custom pragma to count  warnings and tweak exit status

Comment: @yko - Sorry, I misread the part about using `-c` at first. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, this isn't possible.  After all, they are only advisory notices not strictly (no pun intended) errors.  Inversely, however, you can promote warnings to fatal errors at runtime if that helps to address your objective.

```
$ perl -M'warnings FATAL=>q(all)' -cw a.pm ; echo $?
Unquoted string "asd" may clash with future reserved word at a.pm line 2.
255
```

Comment: Does this work? I can not reproduce with warnings and exit status > 0

Comment: @daxim : Thanks for adding what I should have.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this behavior you may use `$SIG{__WARN__}` to die after first warning.
Just like this:

```
package warncounter;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $warnings;

BEGIN {
    $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        $warnings++;
        CORE::warn(@_);
        exit(255);
    };
}

1;
```

And then you may run syntax checking as

```
perl -Mwarncounter -wc test.pl
```

But then perl will exit right after first warning. My first idea was to count number of warnings and set exit status in END block, but in syntax checking mode `-c` END block not being invoked.